# Tkinter - How to change the value of an argument for an event binding with lambda function?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda, event-binding

I have a list named `chosenTestHolder` (imported from the my_config file) that consists of several objects each with the attribute 'sentence'.

When pressing the button 'Press' for the first time, the attribute 'sentence' of the first object in the `chosenTestHolder` should be displayed in the text widget. The next time the button 'Press' is pressed the attribute 'sentence' of the second object in `chosenTestHolder` should be displayed and so on.

I am using lambda event for binding the 'Press' button and tries to use a new sentences as its first arguments after each pressing of the 'Press' button. However, it keeps showing the first sentence.

When searching Stackoverflow I have seen in 
[Using lambda function to change value of an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095790/using-lambda-function-to-change-value-of-an-attribute) that you can't use assignments in lambda expressions but by reading that I still have not figured out how to solve my problem.

Grateful for help! Code is below!

main.py

```
from tkinter import font
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

import my_config 
import Testlist as tl


class TestWidgetTest:

  def __init__(self):

        ram               = tk.Frame(root)
        ram.grid(in_=root,row=0, column=0) 
        self.myText       = tk.Text(ram, height = 5)
        self.myText.grid(row=0,column=1)

        my_config.counter = 0

        self.myButton    = tk.Button(ram, text = 'Press')
        self.myButton.grid(row =1, column =0, columnspan =2)
        indata =[my_config.chosenTestHolder[my_config.counter] , self.myText]
        self.myButton.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',lambda event, arg=indata : self.TagConfigure(event, arg))


  def TagConfigure(self, event, arg):
        arg[1].delete('1.0',tk.END)
        arg[1].insert('1.0',arg[0].sentence)

        my_config.counter += 1


root  = tk.Tk()

TestWidgetTest()
root.mainloop()
```

my_config.py

```
import Testlist as tl

testListHolder  = [ ['Fabian was very tired'],
                ['Thomas light the fire'],
                ['Anna eat a red apple ']]

chosenTestHolder = []
count = 0
while count <(len(testListHolder)):  
    chosenTestHolder.append(tl.Testlist(testListHolder[count][0]))
    count += 1  

counter = 0
```

Testlist.py

```
class Testlist:

    def __init__(self, sentence):

       self.sentence   = sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the assignment of indata.
You do only assign in init.

To get your code working you need to re-configure your sentecte...

> ```
> indata =[my_config.chosenTestHolder[my_config.counter] , self.myText]
> self.myButton.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',lambda event, arg=indata : self.TagConfigure(event, arg))
> ```

I would advise to keep track of the current sentence as an instance variable.

```
class Test_widget(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, args, kwargs)
        self.sentences=["a", "b", "c", "d"] # the data
        self.show = tk.StringVar()          # the current displayed data
        self.show.set("NULL")
        self.counter=0                      # the indexer

        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.show).grid(row=0)
        tk.Button(self, command=self.click).grid(row=1)

    def click(self, event):
        self.show.set("%s"%self.sentences[self.counter]) # use the indexer to access the data
        self.counter = self.counter + 1                  # modify the indexer
        if self.counter = len(self.sentences):           # make sure you dont run in index-err
            self.counter = 0
```

As you see, there is no need at all for the lambdas.

**Edit**
As to your questions:

1. The change in your original code was not intended.
2. I do not see a use case where you can use a lambda for its use inside your code.
   At least none where a lambda is necessary.
   Please remember to use lambda **only and exclusively** if there are 
   **no ( == NULL )** other options.
3. Using **inheritance** (thats what the mechanism is called), you can inherit functions, "default" behaviour from other classes. It is a common mechanism in programming and not exclusive to python.
   It is used like any normal object except you have to call the constructor of the base class (what I do using `tk.Frame.__init__(self, args, kwargs)` inside the `init` method. For more information on inheritance please refer to the uncounted manuals and tutorials available for that topic (google is your friend now that you know what the mechanism is called).

Comment: Thanks! Everything is not clear to me so I have questions: 
1. you wrote: 
indata =[my_config.chosenTestHolder[my_config.counter] , self.myText]
self.myButton.bind('',lambda event, arg=indata : self.TagConfigure(event, arg))
The only difference I see is '<ButtonRelease-1>' replaced by ''. What does this imply?
2.   I have 'reduced' my original code. lambda was used (in the orignal code) since I needed to provide several inparameters . Is there a 'lambda'-solution?
3.   I am new to Python so how to call your Test_widget class given the input argument tk.Frame?      Thanks again!